# JavaScript - How to get at specific value in a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string from which I am trying to get a specif value. The value is buried in the middle of the string.  For example, the string looks like this:

```
 Content1Save
```

The value I want to extract is "1";

Currently, I use the built-in substring function to get to remove the left part of the string, like this:

```
MyString = "Content1Save";
Position = MyString;
Position = Position.substring(7);
alert(Position); // alerts "1Save"
```

I need to get rid of the "Save" part and be left with the 1;

How do I do that?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ANSWER

```
Position = Position.substr(7, 1);
```

QUESTION

What's the difference between these two?

```
Position = Position.substr(7, 1);
Position = Position.substring(7, 1);
```

Comment: Do you KNOW that you will be saving a NUMBER from the middle of a string with nothing but LETTERS around it?

Comment: Do the strings follow any general pattern?

Comment: The number in the string will always be a 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: Regarding your update, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `substr`*<sup>[[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)]</sup>* method. The following example gets the 1 character long substring starting at index 7.

```
Position = Position.substr(7, 1);
```

Or, you can use a regex.

```
Position = /\d+/.exec(Position)[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking into regex, and groups.

Regex is built essentially exactly for this purpose and is built in to javascript.
Regex for something like `Content1Save` would look like this:

```
rg = /^[A-Za-z]*([0-9]+)[A-Za-z]*$/
```

Then you can extract the group using:

```
match = rg.exec('Content1Save');
alert(match[1]);
```

More on regex can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on the rules you have for that middle part. If it's just a character, you can use `Position = Position.substring(0, 1)`. If you're trying to get the number, as long as you have removed the letters before it, you can use `parseInt`.

```
alert(parseInt("123abc")); //123
alert(parseInt("foo123bar")); //NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually trying to search, you'll more often than not need to use something called Regular Expressions. They're the best search syntax JavaScript avails.

```
var matches = Position.match(/\d+/)
alert(matches[0])
```

Otherwise you can use a series of substr's, but that implies you know what is in the string to begin with:

```
MyString.substr(MyString.indexOf(1), 1);
```

But that is a tad annoying.